# sudo service status message missing in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: server, sudo, init.d

i made an update to ubuntu 15 i dont get status messages of the service system anymore.

On the old ubuntu 14.04 when i did:

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                            
... waiting
```

Now i don't get the output anymore:

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

Nothing ... . The status message is just missing. Some ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 and above are using systemd, however still SysV init supported.

To start, stop, restart, status check:

`systemctl <action> <prog>`

Eg:

```
root@mylenovo:~# systemctl status cups
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sel 2015-11-10 20:45:33 MYT; 8min ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 710 (cupsd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           ├─710 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
           ├─789 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           ├─790 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           ├─791 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           ├─794 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
           └─796 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://

Nov 10 20:45:33 mylenovo systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
```

Comment: thx @Aizudinn Zali, for the fast answer. So i guess it wont be possible to turn the feature on ?

Comment: SysV will be removed soon, so i would say get familiar with systemd.

Comment: ah ok, i see. :-)

Comment: If this answered your question appreciate mark as answered.